# Unable to add images with Java Swing

Tags: java, image, swing, toolkit, getresource

```
public class GUICavalli extends JPanel {
int coordx, coordy;
Image img;

public GUICavalli(int y, int x) throws IOException {
    coordx = 0;
    coordy = y;
    setSize(80, 90);
    Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(); //Toolkit: lavorare con la grandezza dello schermo
    switch (x) {
        case 1: {
            img = tk.getImage("cavallo1.jpg");
            break;
        }
        case 2: {
            img = tk.getImage(getClass().getResource("cavallo2.png"));
            break;
        }
    }
    MediaTracker tracker = new MediaTracker(this); //mediatracker: per velocizzare il caricamento e l'inserimento delle immagini
    tracker.addImage(img, 1);
}

public void setX(int m){
    coordx = m;
}

public int getX(){
    return coordx;
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(img,  coordx,  coordy, null);
}
}
```

I have to insert some images and I am using both `MediaTracker` and `Toolkit`, the files on which I am working with net beans I must subsequently insert them on an empty folder together with the images and then pass them on github.

I can't put the images, I tried with the local path but on github it wouldn't work, then I tried to put them in the same folder with the files and to use other types of code, but nothing works.

How can I do this so the images load?

Comment: 1) I removed the switch statements 3 through 10 because they provided no useful information that wasn't already expressed in the first two cases. 2) I do not quite understand what you mean by the references to GitHub. Ultimately the code will be running on a local machine, and that is where the class path will be pointing, to the images must **be on** the local machine unless they are being hot-linked from the GitHub URL. (Not advisable to use, even if it works.) 3) Sidebar: the painting for this `JComponent` is wrong. a) it should be `paintComponent(..)` b) it should call the `super` method..

Comment: .. 3) `g.drawImage(img,  coordx,  coordy, null);` should be `g.drawImage(img,  coordx,  coordy, this);` - given every `JComponent` (like `JPanel`) implements `ImageObserver`, which makes the `MediaTracker` unnecessary. 4) But if it is needed to be certain an `Image` has loaded, I'd use `ImageIO` instead. 5) Probably better to consider these images to be embedded resources and load them via `getResource(..)` from here onward. But the path needs to be sorted out. Show the project structure with at least the (package) location of the class and directory structure leading to the image.

Comment: img = tk.getImage("C:/Users/miste/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Tipsit-garacavalliconthread/src/tipsit/garacavalliconthread/cavallo1.jpg");
                break; I changed and added the full path, I changed null to this but nothing appears

Comment: I .. don't understand why you did that, since it is directly opposite to what I was recommending about `getResource` and URLs. Also, it does not provide the information I need in order to try and help.

Comment: sorry but then I didn't understand what you want me to change